# How to use Xpaths with a regular Scrapy Spider to navigate XML nodes

Tags: xml, python-2.7, xpath, scrapy

I'm using a regular Scrapy "Spider" to get data from HTML pages. However, there is one XML page that it also needs to get data from at the very beginning.

I think I've pretty well gotten down how to use XPath to navigate to the appropriate HTML tags. However, I've got no idea what I'm doing when it comes to XML. About the only thing I could find was the idea of creating another spider, with another parse function. I'd rather not do that as this is just for one of many pages, and I'm also not really even sure how I'd combine the two.

The only item I actually need out of each item is the link.

The basic structure of my XML document is:

```
<item>
      <title></title>
      <link>url</link>
      <description></description>
</item>
<item>
      <title></title>
      <link>url</link>
      <description></description>
</item>
```

The majority of my spider code (just the essentials really) is below

```
class creepySpider(Spider):
# Basically everything up here just determines the start_url

def parse(self, response):
    print self.start_urls
    webpage = Selector(response)
    body = webpage.xpath('//body')

    # Get number of listings and determine number of pages therefrom
    strNumListings = str(webpage.xpath('.//span[@class="titlecount"]/text()').extract())
    strNumListings = strNumListings[4:-3]
    strNumListings = strNumListings.replace(',', '')
    numListings = int(strNumListings)
    resultsPerPage = 25
    numPages = (numListings / resultsPerPage) + 7

    pageNumbers = list(range(numPages))
    pageNumbers = pageNumbers[1:]

    # Begin looping through each page to extract all links
    for page in pageNumbers:
        pageNum = str(page)
        url = str(response.url)
        url = re.sub('/page-(\d*)/', 'page-' + pageNum + '/', url)

        for item in webpage.xpath('item'):
            print 'Searching for items...'

            yield Request(link, callback=self.parse_dir_contents)

        yield Request(url, callback=self.parse)

def parse_dir_contents(self, response):...
```

I tried a number of different things (like webpage.xpath(//item) and trying to accomplish the task using regular expressions), but didn't really get anywhere.

Can I do this while using the standard spider?

EDIT: I think that I asked this backwards :S

I have one initial page, which is an HTML page, that contains the number of listings I'm looking at. I need to first hit that HTML page in order to find out how many pages there will be. After that, I start looking at essentially the same page, but in XML format to grab the links for each individual listing. Each individual listing is in HTML.

So, if possible, I want to start out with an HTML page and grab one field. I calculate the number of pages, then start looking through XML documents for links. Then I navigate to each of those links to get my end data out of the HTML pages.

Comment: Could you show the complete code of the spider? Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at this `XMLFeedSpider` ?   http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#xmlfeedspider

Comment: @Raul I did look at that, but was hoping to not have to create a whole separate spider just for this one page.

Comment: @alecxe I just pasted it :) It's not quite everything. I got rid of extras that performed auxiliary tasks not relevant to what I'm trying to do with the XML document.

Comment: what is stopping you getting the links in parse?

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham Nothing really. It works just great that way. But, I'd rather be hitting the XML page as I get the impression that they're less likely to mind that way? In other words, I worry that I might be more likely to get flagged and asked to stop if I'm going off the regular HTML doc. Am I way off in that assumption?

Comment: Well if you are violating the terms of service by scraping then you are probably going to get your ip banned, if there is nothing in the terms of service stopping you from scraping then I would not worry about it once you are not bombarding the site with requests.

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham Is it typically safer to look at XML documents than HTML? I plan to run the scraper once every 30 minutes or so (every day).

Comment: Without knowing what you are scraping I cannot really give you much advice bar adhere to the terms of service and you should be fine